# Check for duplicate on one row, if unique check on second

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a keyword system for my site but I have hit a bump in the road.

The database table has five rows DATE | USERID | AMOUNT | KEYWORD | ID

When inserting a row into the database it needs to check if the keyword already exists for that userid, if so the amount increments, if not it's inserted with a default value of 1.

So far I have:

```
  $stmt= $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `keywords` (keyword, userId, id) VALUES(?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `amount` = `amount` + 1");
```

How do I check if there is a duplicate of the userid value and increment or insert the keyword based on the result?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a unique index on `(keyword,user_id)`

Comment: I already have one, Added a little more info.

Comment: That was exactly it, I thought the userId had an index, but it turned out it didn't add due to the 1000 byte limit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is:

```
INSERT INTO `keywords`(keyword, userId, id)
    VALUES(?,?,?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `amount` = `amount` + 1;
```

That looks like what you want to do, with possibly one small change:

```
INSERT INTO `keywords`(keyword, userId, id)
    VALUES(?,?,?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `amount` = coalesce(`amount`, 0) + 1;
```

(This is not needed if `amount` has a default value other than `NULL`.)

The other thing you need is a constraint that says that `keyword` is unique.  So, add a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_keywords_keyword on keywords(keyword)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it turned out I had simply made the mistake of not adding the userId's index. thank you for your answer.